# Fastest way to fetch and receive data

Tags: c++, performance, data-structures

I am planning to implement a system which has data and weight attached to each data, the weight attached to the data shall increase/decrease in course of time. I shall be sorting the data with respect to the weight of the nodes.

I am just wondering which will be the fastest way to store the data so that the access time is the minimum. I don't want to use database(s).

I'll be using c++ as the programming language on a Unix system.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Use a normal [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and call [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) whenever a value changes?

Comment: You should take the time and check the spelling before you post a question. You also should take the time to plainly formulate your task and your requirements in terms of measurable quantities. This would be a greater step towards the solution to your problem, more than any answer here could be.

Comment: @moooeeeep :I would be very glad if you could tell me where i went wrong in the spelling.

Comment: Have a look at the edit history: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15678238/revisions - The issues with the spelling were thankfully taken care of by another user.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Min Heap or Max Heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_heap) depending upon how you want to sort your data. Build your heap based on the weights assigned to your data.